# Помогите грамотно организовать наследование С++

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, c++11

```
class Node {
public:
    Element *parent = nullptr;

    void remove() {
        parent->removeChild();
    };
};


class Element : public Node {
public:
    void removeChild() {
    }
};
```

При компиляции естественно выводит ошибку:

```
error: unknown type name 'Element'
        Element *parent = nullptr;
        ^
```

Тогда у меня вопрос, как же мне указать указатель на класс когда он еще не создан? А Element выше Node я написать не могу так как тогда не смогу отнаследовать его от Node.

> P.S. Казалось бы, все просто, должен сделать описание отдельно от
>   реализаций. Но и тут опять же подвох, при описании классов я опять
>   таки должен указать что тип указателя parent это Element* а он на тот
>   момент еще не существует. Если же сделать описание void * parent =
>   nullptr;
>
> а в реализации написать Element * parent; то тогда компилятор говорит
>   что вы пытаетесь инициализировать не статический член класса, вне
>   класса. Если же инициализировать его в реализации конструктора, то все ровно не
>   срабатывает. Выручайте.

Comment: ваша проблема решается применением `forward declaration`

Comment: лол не знал что можно писать просто class Element;

Comment: А можно такое провернуть в двух текстовых файлах?  ну в смысле в четырех node.cpp node.h и element.cpp element.h ?

Comment: Предварительно объявлять можно сколько угодно, реализация должна быть одна. Само подобное применение накладывает некоторые ограничения (см. `incomplete type`). И предпочтительнее в `.cpp` файлах обходится без предварительного объявления.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо вынести объявление класса отдельно от реализации (+ вызов метода наследника должен быть описан после его реализации), например, так:

```
class Element;

class Node
{
public:
    Element* parent = nullptr;

    void remove();
};

class Element: public Node
{
public:
    void removeChild(){}
};

inline void Node::remove()
{
    parent->removeChild();
};
```

Comment: А зачем тогда наследие, если родитель знает о конкретном наследнике?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Это сугубо дело автора, он поставил конкретный вопрос, на который ожидал получить конкретный ответ. Он не просил дать ему совета (по крайней мере я не заметил в его вопросе такой просьбы).

Comment: Зато вопрос поставлен "Помогите грамотно организовать ...". Думаю, это подходит.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Окей, пусть будет так :)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы класс не знал о конкретном наследнике, делается следующим образом:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node* parent = nullptr;

    virtual void removeChild() = 0;
    void remove() {
        parent->removeChild();
    }
};

class Element: public Node
{
public:
    void removeChild() override { /* реализация для каждого наследника своя */ };
};
```

Правда я не совсем понимаю смысла `removeChild`, странное название у метода в такой ситуации. 
В общем случае, если нужно сделать указатель на какого-то произвольного наследника и вызывать функцию, соответствующую конкретному наследнику, пишется указатель на общего родителя, а метод делается виртуальным. Можно не делать его абстрактным.

Comment: тогда я не смогу отнаследовать от Node какой нить класс типа Text который тоже не имеет детей. мне придется в нем реализовывать класс removeChild иначе он останется виртуальным и нельзя будет создавать его экземпляры.

Comment: @user2966664 написал же, что можно не делать его абстрактным. Можно оставить реализацию в родителе пустой

Comment: так я могу просто реализовать children и parent и добавление и удаление в Node! смысл в том что не все Node должны уметь добавлять детей. и я хочу сделать ГРАМОТНУЮ архитектуру по феншую! а раз я делаю реализацию ПУСТОЙ то это КОСТЫЛЬ! и чтобы НЕ делать костылей я сюда и написал. пнятна)?

Comment: @user2966664 Пустая функция - это не костыль. Это распространенная практика и разумный выход. Костыль - это виртуальная абстрактная функция с пустым/полным переопределением в наследниках.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще выглядит странным, что класс-родитель знает о существовании конкретного наследника. Может, лучше в Node сделать поле Node* parent, а в производном классе делать приведение типа?